# df.plot() not showing even after using plt.show()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython

I am working with a California housing price dataframe with multiple columns and want to make a scatter plot between two of them. I am using the following code:

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x = 'longitude', y='latitude')
plt.show()
```

The first line gives me the output:

> matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7fbd88118d30 
> Figure size 432x288 with 2 Axes

But it does not show any plot, the command just executes without any error and no new window opens showing the plot.

I am using ipython(6.4.0) with python(3.6.5) using anaconda and working on the terminal. I can produce plots by using matplotlib (which opens in a new window) but I want to use the pandas plot function. Any idea why this is not working?

[image: Here is the screenshot for the code]

Comment: It happened with me that when working from terminal, the plot appeared but went behind the terminal. I minimized my terminal and all other windows and found the plot on the screen. Minimize the terminal and other open windows/browsers/etc. and see if it's there

Comment: No such thing happening. Usually when I plot with matplotlib a new window opens, but no such window opens with the pandas plot function.

Comment: In the current Jupyter interface, plots automatically appear after the plot command, without using any magic command like `%matplotlib inline`. If that does not happen for you, check 1/ whether it does work for a standard pyplot/matplotlib figure, and 2/ what version of Jupyter you are using.

Comment: In fact, your last sentence should be asked as a new question; it does not appear to be closely related to your actual issue. Consider removing that last sentence, and possibly asking a new question (or search around specifically for an answer to that question).

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am not using Jupyter. That was just a reference if I can get any such functionality in ipython.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here as to how exactly you run this code. In Ipython I would expect the first line to be encapsulated with `<` and `>` and the second line not to appear. Can you clearly state what you do to run the code, which versions are in use and possible show a screenshot? (All *within* the question.)